# IE9 crashing with Bootstrap and :empty selector

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I have strange problem on which I'm working for a while (for more informations, you can look at http://jira.xwiki.org/browse/XWIKI-10661 ).

On some pages (not all of them), Internet Explorer 9 crashes when the :empty selector is used (actually it is .badge:empty and .label:empty). When I say crash, I mean that an error message is displayed 'IE has stopped working' and the process is killed.

It might come from something specific to these pages but I don't manage to find what exactly. But removing these CSS rules (.label:empty and .badges:empty) from bootstrap prevents IE from scratching.

I'm coming to you in the hope that you have ever heard about bugs like this one, and maybe you could give some advices.

Otherwise, it could mean that :empty selector is dangerous with IE9 and that Bootstrap should not use it.

What do you think?

Thanks in advance,

Guillaume D.

Comment: The crash only happens in contentEditable mode, correct?

Comment: You are right, cvrebert.